# Liferay service-builder fail to start

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I created a service-builder and add it to my springmvc-portlet. After deployment, my service-builder was unable to start correctly.

Log:

```
18:26:10,309 WARN  [fileinstall-C:/Users/administrator/Projects/Portal/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4/osgi/modules][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:103] Error while starting bundle: file:/C:/Users/administrator/Projects/Portal/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4/osgi/modules/vp.data.access.service.jar 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: vp.data.access.service [563]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.vt.data.access.exception_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

springmvc-portlet build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.css.builder", version: "2.0.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.liferay.css.builder"

dependencies {
    compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-webmvc-portlet", version: "4.1.9.RELEASE"

    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api", version: "3.0.1"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"
    compile project(":modules:vp-data-access:vp-data-access-api")
}
```

service build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compile project(":modules:vp-data-access:vp-data-access-api")
}

buildService {
    apiDir = "../vp-data-access-api/src/main/java"  
}

group = "vp.data.access"
```

Can anybody help me to solve my problem?

Comment: "Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.vt.data.access.exception" is the culprit. Which module is that in? Did you deploy the -api bundle?

Comment: @OlafKock Thank you for your reply. That error has occurred while group = "???" in service build.gradle and package-path="???" in service.xml did not match.

Comment: As Olaf asked: which module is the `com.vt.data.access.exception` package in? If it's in the api module make sure you're exporting it.

Comment: @HoàngTrần Do I understand correctly that the issue is fixed and you don't need an answer any more? Consider providing the answer here or delete the question in that case. Otherwise, we'll need an answer to the questions that me or Russ asked